# Intersection between Segment and Plane

Tags: geometry, plane-geometry

I have to calculate the point of intersection between a segment and a plane.

The segment is defined by the two points $S_1=(x_1, y_1, z_1)$ and $S_2=(x_2, y_2, z_2)$.

The plane is defined by a point $P=(x_p, y_p, z_p)$ and by the normal $n=(n_1, n_2, n_3)$.

**Important**: I am also interested in knowing if the intersection point falls between S1 and S2 or if it falls in another point of the line passing through these points.

Comment: can you show what you have tried and indicate where the difficulty is?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The key to solving this problem is parametrising the line segment first, for example as
$$S = S_1 + t (S_2 - S_1)$$
so that at $t = 0$, $S = S_1$, and at $t = 1$, $S = S_2$.

Also remember that point $S$ is on the plane with normal $n$ and signed distance $d$ (in units of normal length) from origin, if and only if
$$S \cdot n = d$$
Since point $P$ is on the plane, $P \cdot n = d$.

Therefore, the line extending the segment intersects the plane when
$$S \cdot n = P \cdot n$$
If you work it out, you'll arrive at a single possible solution,
$$t = \frac{n \cdot (P - S_1)}{n \cdot (S_2 - S_1)}$$
There is no solution, when the segment is perpendicular to the plane normal (i.e., segment is parallel to the plane).

If and only if $0 \le t \le 1$, does the segment intersect the plane, at $S$.

If $t \lt 0$, the intersection occurs on the line before $S_1$.

If $t \gt 1$, the intersection occurs on the line after $S_2$.

Comment: There is a possibility that you've overlooked: the segment could lie in the plane, in which case $n\cdot(S_2 - S_1) = 0$. But rather than no intersection, the intersection is the entire segment. To test for this, you calculate $n\cdot(S_2 - S_1)$. If it is non-zero, you proceed as above. If it is zero, you check if $n\cdot S_1 = d$. If so, the entire segment is in the plane. If not, the segment does not intersect the plane.